# Getting MALFORMED_ID on Apex Trigger

Tags: apex

Created a trigger and getting the following error.

I've checked the campaign id and it is correct. it is a 18 digit id. the contact id is also correct. Not sure why I'm getting the error?

`MALFORMED_ID, Invalid campaign id: null: [CampaignId]: Trigger.CreateCampaignMember: line 17, column 1`

My trigger is below. HELP!

```
trigger CreateCampaignMember on Contact (after insert,after update) {

    for(Contact c:Trigger.new)
    {
        List<CampaignMember> cml=[select ID from CampaignMember where Campaign.Id=:c.Campaign__c and Contact.Id=:c.Id];
        if(cml.size()==0)
        {
           CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
           cm.Campaign=new Campaign();
           cm.Contact=new Contact();
           cm.Campaign.Id=c.Campaign__c;
           cm.Contact.Id=c.Id;

           cml.add(cm);
           System.Debug('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ContactId:'+ c);
           System.Debug('<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<CampaignId:' + c.Campaign__c);
           Database.insert (cml);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert an object you must set the foreign key fields - `CampaignId` and `ContactId` - to the ID values of `Campaign` and `Contact` objects that already exist in the database (and so have ID values themselves). For your case - if the fields are guaranteed to have non-null values - values that would be:

```
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
cm.CampaignId = c.Campaign__c;
cm.ContactId = c.Id;
```

or more concisely (because SObjects supported named parameters in the constructor):

```
CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember(
        CampaignId = c.Campaign__c,
        ContactId = c.Id
        );
```

The error message reported in your question shows that `CampaignId` is null in your current code.

References such as `cm.Campaign` and `cm.Contact` are only populated when included in a query; they can't be used to establish relationships between objects.

When you have got it working in its current form you should look into how to [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) this code so that it works when many `Contact` objects are updated at once.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! It really helped solve my problem and saved me a bunch of time! Awesome! Thanks again.